# two modal windows facebook

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, sdk

I am attempting to set up the Facebook SDK in Unity, but am running into a problem.

Upon firing the FB.Login() function, I am greeted with two errors.

One states I can not have two modal windows at once. If I pay close attention, I can see one window is opened onto of another. I have looked on Google but bo clear solution is posted. Any ideas?

> You cannot show two modal windows at once
>   UnityEngine.GUI:ModalWindow(Int32, Rect, WindowFunction, String)
>   EditorFacebookAccessToken:OnGUI() (at Assets/Facebook/Scripts/EditorFacebookAccessToken.cs:53)

Of note: I placed a Debug.log() above said error in script, to see if it is called twice, then the error occurs, however, the function is called once and then the error occurs.

The second error states...

ArgumentException: Getting control 0's position in a group with only 0 controls when doing Repaint
Aborting

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this error myself.  If you go to the code generating the error, you can change:

GUI.ModalWindow(...

to

GUI.Window(...

and it seems to get rid of the error.  This only affects the game when running in the editor, so not a big deal IMO.

Comment: where? this is not a proper answer

Comment: @JohnDemetriou The reason I worded this the way I did is because the code location may change as new SDK's are released.  So the easiest way to find out where this change needs to be made is to look at the error message for the indication of what file the error is occuring in and what line number needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
     ........
```

it happen because the mock dialog conflict with the active panel he consider it as an open ModelWindow ... to fix this problem u have 2 option

option no.1 ) - change the mock dialog GUI to window  ...

double click on the error it will move u directly to the code line >>> the replace

```
        >>>GUI.ModelWindow<<<  with >>>GUI.Window<<<
```

or u can find it in << Assist / FacebookSdK / Sdk / scripts / platform editor / EditorFacebookMockDialog 
under the Gui function .

option no.2 )-close all active panel when using mock dialog then re activate it after

Answer (score 0):

it seems a bug in facebook sdk hope so it will be solved in later versions and this error is just in editor it will work fine after publishing because in EditorFacebookAccessToken script it show a GUI.ModelWindow has property ,only one model window can be shown ay once. You can solve this by replacing GUI.ModelWindow to GUI.Window
or just replace the code in EditorFacebookAccessToken script .Find the code using Ctrl+F

```
GUI.ModelWindow(GetHashCode(), new Rect(windowLeft, windowTop, windowWidth, windowHeight), OnGUIDialog, "Unity Editor Facebook Login");
```

replace with

```
GUI.Window(GetHashCode(), new Rect(windowLeft, windowTop, windowWidth, windowHeight), OnGUIDialog, "Unity Editor Facebook Login");
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using facebook sdk 7.4 and unity 5+ then just change the GUI.ModelWindow to GUI.Window in EditorFacebookMockDialog script.

Comment: cant find the file you are saying

Comment: I cannot find it.